How do I change the camera cent in processing?
I'm creating a 2d minecraft game, and I need to move the center of the camera, for example, set the camera cent to 0.0 and the center of the window will be 0.0
I searched for information on the Internet, asked the community, but did not find an answer.

When I first read minecraft I thought 3D minecract and of (camera() and queasycam), but you want 2D.
There are many ways to achieve a 2D camera effect, but it also depends how you structure your game and the graphics in particular.
One idea is to define ca Camera2D class which has a center point (PVector) and viewport rectangle (think of it as coordinates used to crop what's out of view). This centre point copy values from a player or be follow the please with easing, etc. ...

...in terms of cropping it depends how you render but if you work with pixels (PImage/PGraphics) you can use mask(), or probably simpler to use copy(src, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
